# Javascript events for selections on tablets

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, events, touch

I'm currently trying to get rid of a problem within an application that is supposed to highlight selected textpassages in a document. 
The application is working fine in desktop browsers but is currently having trouble with mobile versions because the browsers(IE 11 mobile) text-selection works differently.

The problem seems to be that the actual selection in the mobile version comes after the mouseup-event that is used to catch the selections. Because of this, the selections aren't updated properly until the next mouseup-event on the document and aren't updated at all if the next mouseup-event happens to take place outside of the document-area.

Right now I'm looking for something like an event that is triggered after the selection or an event that is triggered before a textpart is losing its selection.

So far I've tried most pointer- and touch-events (mostly variations like touchstart, -end, -leave, pointerdown, -out and -up). Further researches only led to selection-events for forms and input-fields which isn't what I'm looking for.

Are there any suggestions for events or workarounds that suit my problem?

Comment: Have you tried Hammer.js? http://hammerjs.github.io/